# VERY basic Slot Machine (checking to see if three labels are equal) Java

Tags: java, if-statement, radio-button, jlabel

### Here is a run down of the program:

1. Three JLables are made.
2. Three buttons are made corresponding to the labels.
3. When a button is pressed it calls a random generator that picks a number between 0-9.
4. Depending on what button is pressed the corresponding JLabel is changed to the number that was generated.
5. Once all three numbers (in each label) are the same it automatically changes the main label to "You Win!".

Number 5 is the part I am having trouble with. I cant seem to be able to compare or tell when all three are the same. I would love if someine could point me in the right direction or provide any kind of help.

Here is the code for the action listener

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class SlotMachinePanel extends JPanel
{

private JRadioButton button1, button2, button3;
private JLabel instr, first, second, third;
private int check1, check2, check3;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Constructor: Sets up the GUI.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public SlotMachinePanel()
{
  // First Panel
  instr = new JLabel ("Please spin a wheel");

  JPanel one = new JPanel();
  one.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(200,50));
  one.setBackground(Color.green);
  one.add(instr);

  // Second Panel
  button1 = new JRadioButton("Spin me!",false);
  first = new JLabel ("1");

  JPanel two = new JPanel();
  two.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(200,50));
  two.setBackground(Color.cyan);
  two.add(first);
  two.add(button1);

  // Third Panel
  button2 = new JRadioButton("Spin me!",false);
  second = new JLabel ("2");

  JPanel three = new JPanel();
  three.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(200,50));
  three.setBackground(Color.green);
  three.add(second);
  three.add(button2);


  // Fourth Panel
  button3 = new JRadioButton("Spin me!",false);
  third = new JLabel ("3");

  JPanel four = new JPanel();
  four.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(200,50));
  four.setBackground(Color.cyan);
  four.add(third);
  four.add(button3);


  ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
  group.add(button1);
  group.add(button2);
  group.add(button3);

  button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
  button2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
  button3.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

  add(one);
  add(two);
  add(three);
  add(four);

  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 210));
  setBackground(Color.green);
  }

  //*****************************************************************
  // listener for button pushes
  //*****************************************************************
  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {

  //--------------------------------------------------------------
  //
  //--------------------------------------------------------------
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    int num;

    Random generator1 = new Random();
    num = generator1.nextInt(9);

    Object source = event.getSource();

    if(source == button1){
      check1 = num;
      first.setText(Integer.toString(num));
    }


    if(source == button2){
      check2 = num;
      second.setText(Integer.toString(num));
    }


    if(source == button3){
      check3 = num;
      third.setText(Integer.toString(num));
    }



    if((check1 == check2) && (check2 == check3)){
       instr.setText("You Win");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Its run using this

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlotMachine
{
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Creates the main program frame.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args)
{


  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Slot Machine");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.getContentPane().add(new SlotMachinePanel());

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Seems to be working  to me..*

I just compiled and ran the code and *when all three have the same number, this if succeeds :*

```
if((check1 == check2) && (check2 == check3)){
```

and the *jlabel instr shows the message*:

```
You Win
```

if you want to *add another message where not all three are the same*, use the following code

```
    if((check1 == check2) && (check2 == check3)){
       instr.setText("You Win");
   }
   else {
           instr.setText("You Did Not Win Yet");
   }
```

*Orelse, what is the problem exactly?*

Comment: glad it works. please accept my answer by clcking the tick box on the left, below the arrow

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if (label1.text.equals(l2.text) && label1.text.equals(l3.text)) doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to check whether the player wins.

**First way of doing:**

Check whether the text on all 3 labels are the same.

```
if (label1.getText().equals(label2.getText()) && label2.getText().equals(label3.getText()))
    instr.setText("Win!");
```

You can place the above codes in the listener when you click the button to generate the random number. This way, every click on the buttons, it checks for a win.

**Second way of doing:**

Every time a random number was generated, you can store that number in 3 `int` variables. Compare the `int` variables instead of the text of the 3 labels.

```
if ((val1 == val2) && (val2 == val3))
    instr.setText("Win");
```

Comment: Great response cant than you enough